# ImageView inside LinearLayout not working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

I have the following layout, each time I try to view it in the `Graphical Layout` it gives the error message below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/my_greeting" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The error

> The following classes could not be found:
>   - ImageView (Change to android.widget.ImageView, Fix Build Path, Edit XML)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's got to do something with your image source `my_greeting`. Check if the source name is right and check if you've given a valid extension. Also, try cleaning the project.

Answer (score 1):

close that file and reopen it. if wont solve the problem just clean and rebuild the project.